# how to change all the selected items background/class instead of change only one selected item in ng-repeat angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How to change all the selected items background/class instead of change only one selected item in ng-repeat? The following is what i have tried but it doesn't work and doesn't show anything as well.

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in CartProducts" ng-click="addToSelection(product)">
    <div class="list">
        <div ng-class="data.defaultClass" ng-show="data.show">
            <i class="icon ion-checkmark-round" style="font-size:30px;text-align:right;opacity:0.5;"></i>
        </div>

        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-class="{checkedFloatingItem: selection.selectedNode == product}">
            <img ng-src="{{product.image}}">
            <h2 style="font-size:20px">{{product.name}}</h2>
            <div style="color:grey">
                SKU: {{product.sku}}<br />
                Price: RM{{product.price}}<br />
                In Stock: {{product.quantity}}
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
AddToCart.addProduct('X142082', 'img/pic.jpg', 'Product 1', 10);
AddToCart.addProduct('Y141414', 'img/pic.jpg', 'Product 2', 1);
AddToCart.addProduct('Z213254', 'img/ionic.png', 'Product 3', 5);
$scope.CartProducts = AddToCart.getProduct();

$scope.selection = {
    selectedNode: []
};
$scope.addToSelection = function (index,node) {
    $scope.selection.selectedNode.push(node);
}
```

CSS

```
.floatingItem {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align:right;
}

.checkedFloatingItem {
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color:#CFD8DC;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: can you zip all your source code and post it / send it to me so I can test it better?

Comment: need some more clarification with posted working code snippet here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://plnkr.co/edit/qlae8dBDUc7vAXPPZx7w?p=preview

Add this to the controller:

```
$scope.isSelected = function(selection) {
    return product in selection.selectedNode;
}
```

In the template:
`<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-class="{'checkedFloatingItem': isSelected(product)}">`

Comment: sorry do u mean this  ng-class="{checkedFloatingItem: product in selection.selectedNode}"

Comment: That is closer. Also add quotes around checkedFloatingItem: `ng-class="{'checkedFloatingItem': product in selection.selectedNode}"`

Comment: hmm... but the console give me this error :    (index):94 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'in' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 33 of the expression [{'checkedFloatingItem': product in selection.selectedNode}] starting at [in selection.selectedNode}].

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't test enough. Check my updated answer, where the "product in ..." is moved to a function in the scope.

Comment: thanks Gavin, it workes. **BUT** there's some problem still, erm would you please brief about whats the meaning for this sentence actually: `'checkedFloatingItem':isSelected(product.id)`  Does it mean isSelected() is one of the property inside 'checkedFloatingItem' Object?

Comment: Its ok.Gavin, I've already get the answer through Angular document. Thanks So Much!